# SQL Server: From ID column to Bitwise/Flag column

Tags: sql-server, database, data-structures, bit-manipulation, database-administration

I have a table of applications (master) with data structure like this:

```
Id | NameColumn | BitFlag
1    'Appl1'      1
2    'Appl2'      2
3    'Appl3'      4
4    'Appl4'      8
```

And a child table like this: ('--' means 'comment')

```
TextColumn    | IdColumn
'SameText'     1  --(app1) 
'SameText'     2  --(app2) 
'OtherText'    3  --(app3)
```

And I want to shrink this table by using the BitFlag column, in a int-bitwise column at the child table, like this:

```
TextColumn    | BitFlag
'SameText'       3 -- (1[app1] + 2[app2])
'OtherText'      4 -- ([app3])
```

I am, currently, making a ConsoleApp to convert from the current structure to the new one and, I am doing this because, today, our 'child table' has more than 300k rows and 90% of are duplicated texts only with a different ApplicationId.

If someone could provide some insights on how to achieve this with SQL-Only 
code or have any thoughts about this, I would be happy to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want that concatendated string like that in the output, or just the bitflag?

Comment: Bleh. Invest in Enterprise Edition and rebuild your tables with page compression, is that still on the table? You're not going to do yourself any favors in the long run by denormalizing.

Comment: if you do not need content in the `()`, just `GROUP BY` and `SUM` could achieve your goal, otherwise use `STUFF` together with `FOR XML PATH('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the parentheses text was for reference, not actual value, thus we can use a simple aggregation.

```
declare @master table (id int, NameColumn varchar(64), BitFlag int)
insert into @master
values
(1,'Appl1',1),
(2,'Appl2',2),
(3,'Appl3',4),
(4,'Appl4',8)

declare @child table (TextColumn varchar(64), IdColumn varchar(64))
insert into @child
values
('SameText',1),
('SameText',2),
('OtherText',3)

select
    c.TextColumn
    ,BitFlag = sum(m.BitFlag)
from
    @child c
    inner join
        @master m on
        m.ID = c.IdColumn
group by
    c.TextColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT c.TextColumn, SUM(m.BitFlag) AS BitFlag
FROM t_child c
LEFT JOIN t_master m
  ON c.IDColumn = m.ID
GROUP BY c.TextColumn;
```

**[RextesterDemo](http://rextester.com/ZEMB97680)**